# How do I align the text vertically with the check box in this list-item?

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework

I am referencing a codepen sample that shows a list of ionic checkboxes that allow swipe and delete functionality.

The ONLY issue I am having is that the styling gets all messed up when this functionality is added. The checkbox text is not vertically lined up with the check box like I need it to. It should be to the right and vertically aligned with the checkbox icon

You can view [the sample codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqbNJx?editors=100) and use that to mess with the styling.

The `ion-list` markup looks like the following:

```
<ion-list show-delete="false"
            on-delete="onItemDelete(item)"
            can-swipe="true"
            option-buttons="itemButtons">

    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" item="item">
       <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="clickItem(item); $event.stopPropagation();" ng-model="item.checked">
        Item {{ item.id }}
      </label>

       <ion-option-button class="button-assertive icon ion-trash-a">
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
```

**Wrong**

[image]

**Right**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-click="clickItem(item); $event.stopPropagation();" ng-model="item.checked" style="display:block;float:left;">
  <span style="display:block;float:left;line-height:28px;margin-left:10px;">Item {{ item.id }}</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi include this css in your css file

```
.checkbox input, .checkbox-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

also you can modify the spacing and color using css.

Answer (score 0):

You're using angular and ionic... Keep up the good standing and use flex elements :) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/